# Creating Word document from Excel Add-In with Office.js

Tags: excel, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

Is it possible to create a `.docx` file from an Excel Add-In written in `office.js`?

My use case would be to open an Excel file (on Windows, so the host is an Excel Application), open the Add-In and the Add-In creates a Word document based on data within the Excel file.

From the things that I've seen, it is not possible to call the `Word.run()` host function from inside a Excel Add-In. I will always get an error that the namespace `Word` is unknown.

Is this even an intended feature to make 'cross-host calls'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had almost the same question: [How to get the active PowerPoint presentation from Excel in office.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63546739/how-to-get-the-active-powerpoint-presentation-from-excel-in-office-js) and got the answer:

> An Office add-in can only work with the Office application (Excel,
> Word, PowerPoint, etc.) in which it is open. It cannot reach outside
> the Office application to work with a document in another Office
> application.

Eventually I moved back to VSTO and C#