# How to get the active PowerPoint presentation from Excel in office.js?

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, yeoman-generator

I'm developing add-in that copy data from Excel to PowerPoint using Yeoman Generator for Office (office.js) but I can't get the opened PowerPoint presentation to write in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Office add-in can only work with the Office application (Excel, Word, PowerPoint, etc.) in which it is open. It cannot reach outside the Office application to work with a document in another Office application.